# How to update a date in a file if applicable and increment the last digit by one if one writes to the file using Vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

**Aim**

The aim is to update a number in a file if one writes to a file using Vim. If the date resides in the file the date part should be left unchanged, but the last digit needs to be incremented by one.

---

**Attempts**

***Attempt 1***

*/home/user/.vimrc*

```
autocmd BufWritePre /tmp/test :%s/\d\{10}/\=strftime("%Y%m%d00")/
```

*/temp/test*

```
4014122100
```

writing the file results in:

```
2014122100

"/tmp/test" 2L, 29C written
```

***Attempt 2***

*/home/user/.vimrc*

```
autocmd BufWritePre /tmp/test :%s/\d\{10}/\=strftime("%Y%m%d00")/
autocmd BufWritePre /tmp/test :%s/\d\{10}/\=submatch(0)+1
```

*/temp/test*

```
4014122100
```

writing the file results in:

```
2014122101

"/tmp/test" 2L, 29C written
```

***Attempt 3***

```
function! ChangeDateIfApplicableAndIncrementLastDigit()
  if !match(getline(1,"$"),strftime("%Y%m%d")) >= 0
    autocmd BufWritePre /tmp/test :%s/\d\{10}/\=strftime("%Y%m%d00")/
  endif
  autocmd BufWritePre /tmp/test :%s/\d\{10}/\=submatch(0)+1
endfunction

autocmd BufWriteCmd /tmp/test call ChangeDateIfApplicableAndIncrementLastDigit()
```

---

**Expected results**

<kbd>Number of writes</kbd><kbd>Expected result</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                          <kbd>2014122101</kbd>     
<kbd>2</kbd>                          <kbd>2014122102</kbd>     
<kbd>3</kbd>                          <kbd>2014122103</kbd>

---

**Current outcome**

<kbd>Number of writes</kbd><kbd>Current outcome</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                          <kbd>2014122101</kbd>       
<kbd>2</kbd>                          <kbd>2014122101</kbd>       
<kbd>3</kbd>                          <kbd>2014122101</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

So, if I get you right, your first and second attempts show that the basic mechanism works, but you're struggling with putting everything together, right?!

The problem is with the `BufWriteCmd`; that hook is supposed to write the buffer contents on its own. The *netrw* plugin uses those to implement remote filesystem access, for instance. You just need to define a single `BufWritePre` hook for your function, and then act depending on whether you've found a current date:

```
function! ChangeDateIfApplicableAndIncrementLastDigit()
  if !match(getline(1,"$"),strftime("%Y%m%d")) >= 0
    %s/\d\{10}/\=strftime("%Y%m%d00")/
  else
    %s/\d\{10}/\=submatch(0)+1
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePre /tmp/test call ChangeDateIfApplicableAndIncrementLastDigit()
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. `1234567890` results in `2014122200`, but this digit persists once subsequent writes have been executed while the expectation was `2014122201`